# Using for loop PHP to print matrix 10*10 in table form

Tags: php

How do I solve this problem to print out matrix which highlights the first row as image

Using for loop PHP to print matrix 10*10 in table form. Note the first column will color with pink
as image 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txwji.png)

Try this code

```
<?php

echo "<table>";

for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++){

    echo "<tr>";

    for($y=1;$y<=10;$y++){
        echo "<td>".$x*$y."</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? have any code?

Comment: yeah, i try this

Comment: So you came to SO to ask for somebody to do it for you? Please make an attempt to do this yourself, When you have some code that you are stuck on then we are more than happy to help you to complete your task.

Comment: yeah, I try to do with that code, but can not complete due to the hight light first row as image

Comment: How good is your CSS?

Comment: my solution was print 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 in first row , but it request print 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 .. with color , can you suggest to that

Comment: As I said, how good is your CSS?  If not, then well you are going to be waiting for a solution that you can't handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achive this we will check if its first row and the first column in nested for loop. Just see the whole there is not much to explain here.

**WHOLE CODE**

```
echo "<table>";
for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++){
    echo "<tr>";

    if($x == 1){
        echo "<td></td>";
        for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){        
            echo "<td style='background-color:blue;'>".$i ."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    for($y=1;$y<=10;$y++){

        if($y == 1){
            echo "<td style='background-color:blue;'>".$x ."</td>";
        }
        echo "<td>".$x*$y."</td>";

    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

You can just edit the design. since you didn't post your css and html code.